# How can I find my IP address when inside a Server

Tags: linux, server, ip

I have a Linux server is hosting in a host company.  I don't know what is the public IP address of the server.  I can only ssh to the server using their Cloud access.  I'm wondering if there's any tools that I can use to tell what is the public IP address of the Server I'm inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This cyberciti.biz article Expline how to find your public IP address](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-my-public-ip-address-from-command-line-on-a-linux/).
To show IP address of server use this command: `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: (`Expline` → *explains*?)(`ip` → [IP address](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address))

Answer (score 0):

I found this website service that you can create a link URL then send a request to that URL to reveal your IP Address and header details which is cool.
https://www.requestheader.com/